# Speech Recogniton in Android Error

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am interested in speech recognition in Android but I can't do it: it is not continuous. If you stop speaking, it doesn't continue, and you have to click on the button again.

I do not want this behaviour..

Does anybody have any suggestions as to what I can to fix this?

Recognise speech only first time  I do not want this behaviour.

Here is the code:

```
    private SpeechRecognizer speech;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    speech.setRecognitionListener(this);

    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en");
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
    this.getPackageName());

    speech.startListening(intent);
    }

     @Override
     public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
     {
     }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] arg0)
         {
        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech()
          {
            }

         @Override
        public void onError(int e)
           {
          }

      @Override
      public void onEvent(int arg0, Bundle arg1)
      {
         }

      @Override
       public void onPartialResults(Bundle arg0)
       {
         }


          public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle arg0)
         {
           }

         @Override
         public void onResults(Bundle data)
         {
           ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayList(
           SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);


           }

           @Override
            public void onRmsChanged(float arg0)
             {
           }
```

Comment: This isn't really a question.  Could you please clarify what it is you are trying to do, and what you have tried so far so that members of the community can try and help

Comment: what you want ?? you don't show any type of information that help for understand.if you want make app Speech Recognition go to url http://www.truiton.com/2014/06/android-speech-recognition-without-dialog-custom-activity/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: In particular, please share the relevant parts of your code. It's impossible to help you without seeing the code you have so far. Imagine I went to the doctor and said I had pain in my stomach, but wouldn't let them examine it - what could they do?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in your [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531721/speech-only-first-time) post, try to call again

speech.startListening(intent);
inside On Results and OnError.